# Is it possible to combine the functions easier?

Tags: javascript

I need to combine some functions (modify 1st function), but I can't do it this way (it works, but is bad for me):

```
var a = function(){alert('a');};
var b = function(){alert('b');};
var c = a;
a = function(){c(); b();};
a();
```

Then I try to do this:

```
var a = function(){alert('a');};
var b = function(){alert('b');};
var rx = /^[\s\S]*\(([\s\S]*)\)\s*{([\s\S]*)}$/;
concat = function(f1,f2)
    {
        var q = f1.toString().replace(rx,'$1|$2').split('|');
        var w = f2.toString().replace(rx,'$1|$2').split('|');
        return (q[0]!=='' && w[0]!=='')?
            new Function(q[0]+','+w[0],q[1]+w[1]):
            (q[0]!=='')?
                new Function(q[0],q[1]+w[1]):
                new Function(w[0],q[1]+w[1]);
    };
a = concat(a,b);
alert(a);
```

It works, but may be exist an easier way?

Comment: for performance or similar questions, one should post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of here

Comment: Your `concat` function is extremely poor.

Answer (score 5):

```
function concat(a, b) {
    return function() { 
        a.call(this, arguments); 
        b.call(this, arguments); 
    };
}
```

Eval is evil, and parsing code with regexes is more evil.

---

You can even add varargs support:

```
function concat() {
    var funcs = arguments;
    return function() { 
        for (var i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++)
            funcs[i].call(this, arguments); 
    };
}
```

Comment: Ok... And if I want to summ function body?

Comment: if it isn't concatenation, but replacement of part?

Comment: +1. Simple and effective. I like the variable arguments version.

Comment: @3y3: I still have no idea what you mean.

Comment: My best guess at what 3y3 means by "replacement of part" is that he or she wants to concatenate only part of one of the functions with the other function. E.g., if the first function has ten lines, replace the last five lines with the body from some second function. Not that the regex in the question does that, but it does seem to want to extract the pieces of the two functions and build a single new function, which is pointless unless the function bodies and/or argument lists get modified...

Comment: @nnnnnn: That is likely to be what he's asking, but it's a bad idea and will not work in general.  My `concat` is a simple example of a higher-order function.  See my [jsDelegate library](https://github.com/SLaks/jsDelegate) for a more sophisticated version.

Comment: Yes, it seems a bad idea to me. I don't recommend the `new Function()` approach, but hypothetically if somebody did want to do that and they knew enough about the content of a function body to extract the appropriate bit via regex (and/or other string methods) then presumably they know more than enough to just directly generate the new function. Far better to just modularise the code properly in the first place.